Ubuntu partition renamed after installing Airflow on Docker - how to revert partition mount to original name?
I'm a recent Ubuntu 24.04 and Docker user. I'm using Docker Engine 27.3.1. I have 2 disk partitions as "data" and another partition where OS is installed. I installed Apache Airflow using Docker on the "data" partition. Now in /media/user/ that "data" partition has changed into "data1" and a new folder "data" has been created, but the partition name in the disk section has not changed. I want to remove that data folder and make my partition mount as "data". How can I do that? What could be the reason for this issue?
Here are some screenshots for further clarification.



